# GZipStream to ZipArchive

Tags: c#, zip, gzip, archive, gzipstream

I'm working on a project where I want to obtain the file from a compressed archive which only holds a single file. The files I'm interested in opening are of the file extension .als (Ableton Live Set) and from 7Zip I've found they use the gzip compression type.

I've found some code which let's me easily obtain the file from the archive:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    var entryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txt_file_select.Text);
    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
    {
        String fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Debug.WriteLine(fileContent);
    }
}
```

This code opens the file from the stream `zipToOpen` which has the same filepath as `txt_file_select.Text`. The single entry that I'm interested in seems to always have the same name as the zipped file itself so this should always give me an entry for any compressed archive that uses zip type. But this code does not accept gzip types in the current state as I get:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' in System.IO.Compression.dll 
> An exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.dll but was not handled in user code 
> End of Central Directory record could not be found.

I've found that you can open gzip type archives using the `GZipStream` class. so I added this line:

```
using (GZipStream zipToOpen = new GZipStream(new FileStream(txt_file_select.Text, FileMode.Open), CompressionMode.Decompress))
```

which still results in the same exception being thrown. I'm assuming the problem is in converting from `GZipStream` to `ZipArchive`.

Here is a simple reproducible example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Compression;

String filepath = @"path\to\als\file.als";

using (GZipStream zipToOpen = new GZipStream(new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        var entryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
        ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry(entryName);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(entry.Open()))
        {
            String fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(fileContent);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert the GZipStream into a ZipArchive?

Comment: What did it _actually_ say when `GZipStream` failed? There's no way it said "End of Central Directory record could not be found", since there is no such thing in a gzip file. Note that despite the similarity in names, the gzip format and zip format are entirely different.

Comment: @MarkAdler That was the exception that I get on the line where I make the archive variable. so it's thrown by ZipArchive

Comment: So you think that there is a zip archive inside a gzip stream? Why do you think that?

Comment: @MarkAdler Yes I thought that GZipStream can be processed into a zip file

Comment: That makes no sense. Decoding a gzip stream, and the decoding the result of that as a zip file is _not_ "processing into a zip file". Have you simply looked at the result of reading the gzip stream?

Comment: @That might work better... I'll go over the documentation once more...